Add Imports to Existing WordPress Import Map
How can imports be added to the existing WordPress import map?

Preparing the Module
I have a JavaScript module threeDTest.js which is enqueued using a PHP short-code (set to run everywhere):
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_three_d_script');

function enqueue_three_d_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script_module('three-d-script', SCRIPTS_DIR . 'threeDTest.js');
}


threeDTest.js requires the following imports:
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';


Since threeDTest.js is a module, it requires a corresponding import map within the HTML <head> tag:
<script type="importmap">
    {
        "imports": {
            "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.167.1/build/three.module.js",
            "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.167.1/examples/jsm/"
        }
    }
</script>


Existing WP Import Map
But since WordPress already has an import map in the <head> tag, I am unable to add a new import map (there can only be one). The existing WordPress import map:
<script type="importmap" id="wp-importmap">
{
    "imports": {
        "@wordpress/interactivity":"https://local-test-site.test/wp-includes/js/dist/interactivity.min.js?ver=ca61638fbb0e7d19027303ef6f49511b"
    }
}
</script>


Attempts
I have tried the following, but neither worked:

Adding a custom import map using add_action('wp_head', 'add_three_d_import_map'), but this creates an additional import map (there can only be one).
Injecting the required imports using JavaScript, but learned all the imports need to be present at page load.


Proof of Concept
Adding the code below to the print_import_map() function in class-wp-script-modules.php (core WordPress file in /wp-includes) does work:
$import_map['imports']['three'] = "https://unpkg.com/three@0.167.1/build/three.module.js";
$import_map['imports']['three/addons/'] = "https://unpkg.com/three@0.167.1/examples/jsm/";

But since class-wp-script-modules.php is a core WordPress file, it is subject to change in updates. So editing it manually is not an ideal solution.

Any Ideas?
Is there a clean solution to adding your own imports to the already existing WordPress import map?
Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Turns out to be quite simple in WordPress 6.5.
Use wp_register_script_module to register the imports, and include them as dependencies in wp_enqueue_script_module:
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_three_d_script');

function enqueue_three_d_script() {
    wp_register_script_module(
        'three',
        "https://unpkg.com/three@0.167.1/build/three.module.js",
        array(),
        null
    );
    wp_register_script_module(
        'three/addons/',
        "https://unpkg.com/three@0.167.1/examples/jsm/",
        array(),
        null
    );
    wp_enqueue_script_module(
        'three-d-script', 
        SCRIPTS_DIR . 'threeDTest.js', 
        array('three', 'three/addons/'), 
        null
    );
}

